# Is there someone tweeting about new Esperanto books?

Tags: literature

I'd like to follow som new media that give me updates on new, interesting books. I'm already in Literatura Babilejo on Facebook and Telegram, but I'm looking for different channels.

Is there maybe an Esperanto publisher that tweets new books?

Answer (score 3):

Best I can offer is [@UEAViva](https://twitter.com/UEAViva) (Universala Esperanto Asocio, the main publisher of eo books) and [@esperanto](https://twitter.com/esperanto) (most active eo Twitter handle), both of whom every now and again upload new books, articles, etc.

Comment: Wow, those are great tips! Thank you so much.